# MySQL on Debian, unknown variable 'set-variable=local-infile=0'

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

I have a dedicated server which is running MySQL.

In the my.cnf configuration file, I added this configuration a long time ago :

```
set-variable=local-infile=0
```

It was working fine, but since yesterday, my server started to act strangely, and after a reboot, I was unable to start mysql.

The probleme was located at this configuration, as stated in the logs :

```
[ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'set-variable=local-infile=0'
```

And after having commented this line, mysql started fine.

Is there something I missed, an update that break this type of configuration ? I'm really wondering what happened.

I run MySQL **5.5.31-0+wheezy1**

(Note: I'm aware of this quite [similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/322493/mysql-service-wont-start-error-usr-libexec-mysqld-unknown-variable-set-var), but I'm looking to understand what changed, not where is the problem ;))

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the set-variable. That is no longer used in the my.cnf

Comment: Do you have an idea about why/since when this configuration is obsolete / abandonned ?

Comment: Versioning. MySQL changed how they run their config.